# Trigger or Javascript in processmaker?

Tags: processmaker

The subject is:
I have connected one of my processes to an external sql database through Database Connection( very hard of course due to lack of sql connection!). In my dynaform i have two textbox that are named RefNumber and Value and also i have a button. i want to enter a number in RefNumber and press the button and  related value to that number appears in Value (i have that number and its corresponding value in my database that i earlier connected).
So the first question is : Which one should i use ?Trigger or Javascript?
and the second question: what is the code?

Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you whether you want to update your value at database side or backend side.

Also I would like to add that **trigger sometimes fail** due to bad connection issues or some random user shit error and it might happen that your data is updated and value is not incremented(updated). **So I recommend not to use trigger, yes trigger saves time but sometimes it doesn't work.**

And benefit of doing it at backend side is that if your data is not updated, failed, value will also not.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create an API on server app processmaker(use plugin to create api). Or the server BackEnd will configure CORS enabled so that the client side can call the api.
In dynaform, use ajax to make request to api.